# Are the Nox ascending?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

In Stargate SG1, S1E8, the Nox have mysterious powers like making things disappear and reviving people. They do not seem to wear any tech in order to vanish. Furthermore, it is clearly visible that they are not using tech to revive Lya:

[image: Revival of Lya]

They simply hold their hands above her and revive her. Also, they are not able to revive and be invisible at the same moment, hinting at a capacity problem. I.e., they can't concentrate on reviving somebody and be invisible.

Also, in S1E17 (Enigma - the one with the Tollans), Lya is able to open a wormhole from earth to her planet. The gate is not dialing but the wormhole is created. [Video of the scene were Lya is creating the wormhole](https://youtu.be/X18XGc1OHfk?t=183).

This remembers me of the powers of ascended or nearly ascended people, e.g. [Adria](http://stargate-wiki.de/wiki/Adria) or Anubis son.

Are the Nox in the process of ascending and these are their powers or is it part of their highly evolved tech?

Comment: Personally, I don't think they were going for ascension, They appeared perfectly happy with their life as it existed. But we have no way of knowing where their "powers" were the result of very advanced tech (Which they demonstrated when they revealed their large very advanced city IIRC) or mental powers they had developed. But I suspect it is a combination of both.

Comment: I agree with @NJohnny, they might well have been *capable* of ascension but chose not to.  Or perhaps they are on a different path - perhaps a superior one! - their powers might look similar in effect to those of ascension but that doesn't mean the cause is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR**

- SPOILERS AHEAD TO STARGATE ATLANTIS!
- No, they were not.
- They were healing/reviving her; we just don't know how.
- We don't know if the Nox know how to ascend.
- The Alterans had to research how to do it.

So, the Nox were not trying to ascend in that situation. They were actually trying to help Lya. She was hurt after being attacked by the Goauld and they were helping her. We don't know much about the Nox culture/technology, but (just as the snakes have the ability to) they have the ability to bring someone back from the dead if they need to.

Despite this amazing ability however, the Goauld do not have the ability to ascend. And from what we know there is nothing to say that the Nox have the ability either; despite how advanced they are. From what we see we know the Nox have the ability to make things invisible, make cities hover, bring beings back from the dead, turn the gate on without dialing, and somehow know if people are only pretending to sleep (might not be so impressive, but...).

Mind you, we have no clue how these things work for them, but we know that they can do each of those things and likely more. Also keep in mind, that in SG1 Season 2 Episode 21 "1969" Cassandra had that device on her hand that allowed her to dial the gate with a swipe of her hand. Even if this was a 'pre-programmed' dial there is nothing to say that Lya didn't have that (even something embedded into her skin or whatever) to allow her to do that as well.

Now those are all impressive abilities, but we never see or hear of the Nox ascending. The Alterans are the only ones (minus Anubis, Daniel, and the Ori) that have attained ascension. Technically, the Ori were still Alterans when they learned how and we know that Anubis and Daniel only ascended because of the knowledge they got from the Ancients.

However, the Alterans learned how to ascend through research:

From Stargate Atlansis Season 1 Episode 3 "Hide and Seek" we know that the Alterans somehow found out about living beings of energy and managed to lure and trap one in a containment device. This being they studied and actually researched how to ascend.

Assuming that the Nox never discovered or cared about these beings there is no guarantee that they would have ever learned how to ascend. If the beings of energy only existed in the Pegasus galaxy then the Nox never would have even gotten the chance...

In the end, the Nox are extremely advanced... We just have no real hint as to how advanced. All we know is that they are one of the other three super races that were allied with the Alterans. They seem to live a peaceful life and from what we can tell they don't even seem to leave their planet unless it is absolutely necessary...

Comment: Sorry but there doesn't seem to be anything in here to back up your claim that we can know the Nox weren't ascending..

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica - I thought I did a decent job of explaining it in my answer, but if you say so... I can't show you undeniable proof of something when there is no proof of it to speak of... I'm not sure what else you are looking for. That is like saying that since we never actually see it happen on screen there is no way to say that the Asgard weren't ascending either... sure, that is technically true, but let's be real. Lack of proof doesn't constitute proof.

Comment: Well, I guess that's my point - there is no proof either way; all we have is speculation. So, really, there is no answer ;) Yet you claim "no they were not" - I don't think your answer has anything to substantiate that claim.

Comment: Well, in the episode in question we see both the SGC team as well as the snake team raised from the dead and the Nox cope to the fact that they did it. Later in the episode we hear confirmation that they are using the same ritual to bring back the child that was killed and that they are unable to protect themselves during the action. They were raising the deceased Nox from the dead, not ascending. As I state in my answer we also know that ascending was researched with proof from an entirely different galaxy. Sure, we don't know, but the evidence of what we know suggests pretty heavily one way.

Comment: Sorry, not seeing it. Near-ascended beings have shown some remarkable powers, including healing and bringing people back from [near-]death. That's why the question was asked: to find out whether the Nox's abilities stemmed from this process. Nothing you've put forth here rules that out.

Answer (score -1):

Almost all of the advanced civilizations have technology that reads their thoughts and performs predetermined actions. For instance, the Goa'uld use a verity of handheld devices that can be used to heal wounds, torture people, produce shockwaves, or remote control other technologies like the ring gates. The Tollan similarly have multiple devices attached to their sleeves, which only appear to have 2 or 3 buttons, but perform very complex tasks, leading me to believe the buttons merely activate or deactivate the device, and the rest of it's functionality is controlled by thought. They use these devices to record and share feelings, transmit messages lightyears away, and phase shift through walls. It is therefor conceivable that the Nox simply conceal their technology. Perhaps their ability to cloak things is built into their clothing, and the healing machine was disguised as a primitive alter of some kind. Their inability to cloak and heal simultaneously may simply be explained by the inability of the device's users to multitask, rather than the power consumption or level of ascension. However, their unwillingness to share their technology and/or knowledge prevent us from knowing which it is, thus we're forced to call it magic.

Comment: So this doesn't really answer the question if these displays are simply sufficiently advanced technology (though you seem to assume it is) or if the Nox have powers because they are near-ascended.  Since you make the assumption they have sufficiently advanced technology, you need to justify that assumption and give some evidence.